# change type attribute from submit to button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the type attribute from `submit` to `button` using JavaScript or jQuery? I use an `input` 
element like `<input type="submit" name="submitform"/>`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change the property of the native DOM node:

```
document.getElementsByName("submitform")[0].type = "button";
```

Do it with jQuery:

```
$("input[name='submitform']").prop("type", "button");
```

But **remember that you cannot change `input` types in Internet Explorer 8 and below**.

Comment: .prop will not work with older jquery versions(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: @BogdanM. - `.prop()` was added in jQuery 1.6. If you're still below that then it's definitely time for an upgrade.

Comment: Then instead of changing attribute ,shall i proceed to add onsubmit for the same form? do you have any idea @james Allardice

Comment: @av1000 - I'm not sure what you mean. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

You can use setAttribute property something like this in javascript

```
document.getElementsByName("submitform").setAttribute('type', 'button');
```

for jQuery

```
$('input[name="submitform"]').attr("type", "button");
```

Comment: just a heads-up: there is a difference in using .attr and .prop, see  http://api.jquery.com/prop/ ("the difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.") and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input').prop('type','button');
```

Comment: @av1000 - It will work but bear in mind the point I made in my answer - it *won't* work in IE8 and below.

Comment: Then instead of changing attribute ,shall i proceed to add onsubmit for the same form? do you have any idea @james Allardice

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('input[name="submitform"]').attr('type', 'button');
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
$('input[name="submitform"]').attr('type','button')
```

Answer (score 0):

For `<input type="submit" name="submitform"/>`,

write jquery as:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="submitform"]').attr('type', 'button');
});
</script>
```